# A-frame screen click instead of "w" press to walk

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe

i am currently exploring the wonderful world of A-frame. i have added the wasd controls (which works great) however id like to replicate the function of the w button when clicking the screen, so basic vr headsets can also walk around, (think google cardboard with the one little button on the top), ive done some googling and cant seem to find anything, i also wondered is it possible to simulate the w key being pressed when clicking,(random idea, i know) but as always any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to reuse the `wasd-controls` you can tell it that **w** is pressed, with a simple hack ([original source](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/v1.4.0/src/components/wasd-controls.js#L211)):

```
(wasd-controls-reference).keys['KeyW'] = true // or false
```

which could be toggled on `touchstart`/`touchend` like:

```
document.body.addEventListener("touchstart", () => {
  const controlsElement = document.querySelector("[wasd-controls]");
  const controls = controlsElement.components["wasd-controls"];
  controls.keys['KeyW'] = true;
})
```

Check it out [here](https://gftruj.github.io/webzamples/aframe/touch-controls/).